# Are there any known global effects of the Mediterranean sea evaporation and refilling?

Tags: geology, climate, mediterranean

This is a broad subject I realize, but I'm looking for specific geologically observed answers of global effects elsewhere, between about 5.96 and 5.33 million years ago when the Mediterranean sea was blocked off from the Atlantic and dried up into the Mediterranean valley or salt flat, or whatever term you like.

The Mediterranean sea used to be more connected to the Atlantic than it is today, perhaps not ocean, but the water freely flowed between, perhaps comparable to the gulf of Mexico and Atlantic ocean today.

Image of what the continents may have looked like 20 million years ago.

[image: Europe 20 million years ago]

[Source of image](https://infographic.tv/map-europe-20-million-years-ago/).

About 6 million years ago, North Africa and Spain collided, blocking any connection between the sea and the ocean and the water and not long after the water dried up - leaving salt deposits that are mined today.   I'm thinking it was a great big mess as well, with limited outlets or inlets - kind of like a massive Salton sea, but . . . I digress.

[Pretty good article here](https://phys.org/news/2017-09-geologists-mediterranean-sea-million-years.html) with some detail but not specifically what I'm looking for.

That much water loss (the current Mediterranean is about 3.75 million km$^3$ (900,000 cubic miles) of water which corresponds to about 1.2 meters (4 feet) of sea level rise), so sea level rose about 1.2 meters 5.96 million years ago and then gave back those 1.2 meters (4 feet) when the Mediterranean refilled.

Question is, are there any observed global effects from that period either beginning or ending?  Any distinct changes elsewhere on Earth either 5.96 million years ago or 5.33 million years ago?    I'm mostly curious if this event was large enough to have a global effect.